# Stop the built in Podcasts app from downloading podcasts

Tags: 8.1, podcast

I tried out the built in Podcasts app and decided that I liked Podcast Lounge, which I had already paid for before WP 8.1 came out, better.

My problem is that the built-in Podcasts app keeps downloading podcasts, eating up my storage.  I can't uninstall the built-in Podcasts app.  I've cleared out all the favorites.  What else do I have to do to make it stop doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you removed the subscriptions from within the podcast app? This would manage its own list separate from any apps.

Also, you could set the number of episodes to keep to "None (stream only)"

Comment: I don't see "subscriptions" in the podcast app, just favorites.  Everything in there is unchecked.

Comment: go to collection -> audio / video. There are all the podcasts you have subscribed to (therfore "subsciption"). There you can also manage or delete all of the podcasts you want gone.

Comment: Actually the problem continues, every day or so I delete all my subscriptions and they're associated downloads, but they keep coming back.